# tearDown not called for unittesting with Tornado

Tags: python-2.7, tornado, python-unittest, rethinkdb-python

I'm using Rethinkdb and Tornado with `rethinkdb.set_loop_type("tornado")`

I'm using python unittests to test my server routes.

Here is my unittest base class:

```
class ServerTest(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(ServerTest, self).setUp()

    def get_app(self):
        return Application(self.routes, debug = False)

    def post(self, route, data):
        result = self.fetch("/%s" % route, method = "POST",
                                body = json.dumps(data)).body
        return json.loads(result)

    def tearDown(self):
        super(ServerTest, self).tearDown()
        conn = yield r.connect()
        yield r.db("test").table("test_table").delete().run(conn)
        conn.close()
```

I noticed that `setUp` is running properly, but `tearDown` is not. All my unittests are passing properly, but print statements in tearDown are not called.

EDIT: I've narrowed it down to the fact that I'm calling yield in tearDown.

EDIT: Adding @gen.coroutine to tearDown shows the print statements, but doesn't perform the delete on the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `yield` and `@gen.coroutine` makes a function asynchronous, which changes its interface: the caller *must* be aware of this change. The `unittest` framework does not know anything about coroutines, so no method called by `unittest` may be a coroutine.

Instead of `@gen.coroutine`, you can use [`@tornado.testing.gen_test`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html#tornado.testing.gen_test), which lets you use `yield` in tests, and in methods called from `setUp` and `tearDown`, but not `setUp` and `tearDown` themselves (because the generator machinery cannot work before `super().setUp()` or after `super().tearDown()`. Use a helper method with `gen_test` and call it *without* `yield` in `tearDown`:

```
def tearDown(self):
    self.tearDownHelper()
    super(ServerTest, self).tearDown()

@tornado.testing.gen_test
def tearDownHelper(self):
    conn = yield r.connect()
    yield r.db("test").table("test_table").delete().run(conn)
    conn.close()
```